# Bootstrap dismissable alerts

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have a form in my django project and I want to display the form errors if any when the user clicks submit. This is one of my fields (working on getting one right before I move on to others)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="title">Title
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {{ form.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3">
{#                                        <p class="text-danger">{% for error in form.title.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}</p>#}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <p>{% for error in form.title.errros %} {{ error }} {% endfor %}</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

However I have 2 issues :

1. The alert shows up when the form loads, without the error message:

[image: alert on form load]

2. When I dismiss the alert the form styling gets messed up:

[image: styling messed up]

I cant seem to understand what the issue is.

I was able to get the error message without the bootstrap alerts using this code. However it would be great to let the user dismiss an alert after the correction has been made:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="title">Title
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    {{ form.title }}
    </div>
    <span class="help-block">
        <p class="text-danger">{% for error in form.title.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe, you will find http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest helpful since it takes care of all the HTML/CSS work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` containing the alert has no closing `</div>` tag, that messes up the form when you dismiss the alert. As for the alert showing up when the form loads - there's already some content in the alert div (the 'close' button) so it is displayed. You have to render it conditionally (only when there are corresponding errors to show):

```
    <div class="col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3">
        {% if form.title.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <p>{% for error in form.title.errors %} {{ error }} {% endfor %}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: I did try this. However the error text is not displayed. Its is only displayed when I do it the way Ive shown it in the last code snippet in my post

Comment: This is probably a styling problem - errors are rendered as unordered list, so I think they appear in the hidden area below the bottom edge of the alert (notice on your screenshot how the 'close' button is clipped, the messages are even lower). You can use the debugging tools in your browser (Shift + Ctrl + C for Chrome / Firefox on Windows / Linux, don't remember other browsers or Mac shortcuts) to confirm it's there and play with the CSS to get it shown.

Comment: I did use developer tools and "inspect element" on the div. It shows only the `alert div` and `x` button that is generated but no text.

Comment: Ah, you have a typo - `{% for error in form.title.errros %}`, corrected it in my answer now (err**ro**s instead of errors)

Comment: Oh my god such a stupid typo took all my morning. Thanks a lot!